# How to interrupt streaming file on a condition?

Tags: perl, asterisk, agi

I`m using **Asterisk::AGI** and I need to stream a music file and interrupt streaming according to some background condition (like checking data in DB, if changed smth -> interrupt streaming).

Can somebody advice/point me where should I look for a solution?

Thanks a lot
Pavel

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/930353/1255289

Answer (score 1):

You can use AsyncAGI command, which will play musiconhold class unless get some other action

After that you have use Asterisk::AMI to transfer that channel to other context/dialplan

No, there are no any way do it using just AGI interface without AMI.